# Using Matlab FFT to extract frequencies from EEG signal

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency

I am new to BCI. I have a Mindset EEG device from [Neurosky](http://neurosky.com) and I record the Raw data values coming from the device in a csv file. I can read and extract the data from the csv into Matlab and I apply FFT. I now need to extract certain frequencies (Alpha, Beta, Theta, Gamma) from the FFT.

Where Delta = 1-3 Hz

Theta= 4-7 Hz

Alpha = 8-12 Hz

Beta = 13-30 Hz

Gamma = 31-40 Hz

This is what I did so far:

```
f = (0:N-1)*(Fs/N);
plot(rawDouble);
title ('Raw Signal');
p = abs(fft(rawDouble));
figure,plot (f,p);
title('Magnitude of FFT of Raw Signal');
```

Can anyone tell me how to extract those particular frequency ranges from the signal?? Thank you very much!

Comment: Look at the MATLAB documentation for bandwidth filters. That should be easier than going through an fft first.

Comment: PLEASE ANYBODY ANSWER TO MY QUESTION HERE 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167374/performing-fft-on-eeg-signal-using-matlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenient analysis of EEG data with MatLab you might consider to use the EEGLAB toolbox  (http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/) or the fieldtrip toolbox (http://fieldtrip.fcdonders.nl/start).

Both toolboxes come with good tutorials:

http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/eeglabtut.html

http://fieldtrip.fcdonders.nl/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to start off with MATLAB's [periodogram](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/signal/ref/periodogram.html) function, rather than trying to use the FFT directly. This takes care of windowing the data for you and various other implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to filter your signal in those ranges after you load your data.
E.g.

> band=[30 100] eeglocal.lowpass(band(2)).highpass(band(1));

then you can use select the time you want to process.

That should be all you need.